# How can I aviod displaying macro undefined error when I use #ifndef in Vscode?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04
- Software: Vscode

  - C/C++ Extensions by Microsoft

c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

If the `main.c` is

```c
#ifdef CONFIG_LONG_NAME
#define USE_LEN 3
#else
#define USE_LEN 0
#endif
```

and the macro `CONFIG_LONG_NAME` is in the **autoconfig.h** that is generated automatically at compile time.**So some macros can not be finded directly.**

I can add it to `c_cpp_properties.json` to avoid display error `identifier "CONFIG_LONG_NAME" is undefined C/C++(20)`.

```
"defines": [
    "CONFIG_LONG_NAME"
],
```

But if I use `#ifndef CONFIG_LONG_NAME`, what can I do? I don't want to see this error.By the way,I only use vscode to **edit** C project.

Comment: Since your source checks `#ifdef` or `#ifndef`, I don't see why you should get an error from VSC. The IDE, even if still in its infancy, should be able to accept this without an error. Where or when exactly do you get this error?

Comment: Oh,I'm sorry.I have looked this project up again and I have some details to understand.This question will be re-edited after I understand it.